# Java: want binary search of subset of an array

Tags: java, binary-search

In Java, Arrays.binarySearch always searches the entire array.  Sometimes part of the array has not been filled.  Is there any function to search a part of the array, e.g.

```
int binarySearch(int[] a, int end, int value)
```

Yes, I could just use a `TreeMap<Integer>` but I have a lot of these and `TreeMap<Integer>` uses several times more memory than int[].

And yes, I can certainly write a binary search, but given the presence of Arrays.binarySearch it seems I shouldn't have to write my own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an overloaded [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) that does exactly this:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] a,
                               int fromIndex,
                               int toIndex,
                               int key)
```

It is available in Java 1.6+.

Comment: Oh duuuuuh!  For some reason Google 'Java X' always presents old doc first.  Now I feel silly for asking.  If I could downvote my own question, I would.

Comment: @kevincline: You are quite right about Google and old Java docs. I usually search for `java6` or `java7`, e.g. `Arrays java6`.